# read parquet files and skip rows that don't follow the schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, parquet

I have a bunch of parquet files stored on a S3 location which I want to load as a dataframe. When doing this, however, there are a few lines that I don't want/need to be part of the dataframe. What is the best way to filter the parquet files in such a way that these rows are not included in the dataframe? The parquet files consists out of gzipped csv files

The schema that I want to use is:

```
schema = StructType() \
      .add("col_1",LongType(),True) \
      .add("col_2",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col_3",StringType(),True)
```

The rows that I want to skip are rows in which either col_1 is empty or a string value and or col_2 is empty. Hope this question makes kind of sense...

PS: I should add that using the following syntax and trying the read the parquet files as a dataframe results in a fail:

> df=
> spark.read.format("parquet").schema(schema).load('s3_bucket/folder_parquet_files/*')

Not directly, but when doing a display on the file am getting the following notification:
Error while reading file XXXXX. Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [col_1], Expected: LongType, Found: BINARY
Caused by: SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a simple filter, you don't have to check `col_1` has a string value or not because it's of type long so the only values it can have are long or nulls:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, isnull
filtered_df = df.filter((~isnull('col_1')) & (~isnan('col_2')) & (col("col_2") != ""))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can do any operations such as filtering on isnull, but when I do a display I still get the following notification:  Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [col_1], Expected: LongType, Found: BINARY
Caused by: SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException

Comment: The error is probably because of a type mismatch between your parquet and your schema for column col_1, try to change col_1 to string in your schema check it's value and adapt it to your needs

Comment: Yes that works fine thanks! Out of curiosity, would it be possible to do a similar filter on the parquet files instead before reading them as a dataframe?

Comment: No, unfortunately you have to load the parquet into a dataframe in memory to start doing transformations on it, you can't just apply it to the parquet files on disk.

Comment: okay, I appreciate you taking the time to explain this. I just accepted your reply.